# Process.Env Isn't Populated in React App on Azure

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, pm2

I'm trying to get a React app running in Azure App Services and having difficulties getting environmental variables to work.

### Locally

When running locally I'm using a `.env.local` file to load environmental variables (which isn't checked into git).

```
REACT_APP_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:5000
```

I can then use it in my application by referencing it using `process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL`. Everything is working as expected.

### On Azure

Now I'm trying to get the same thing working in Azure. I've setup configuration using Application Settings (described in their documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux#access-environment-variables) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-app-settings)).

I can use kudu to get to the debug console and see that the environmental variable is being set.

[image: kudu debug console]

But using `process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL` is not pulling in that value. If I `console.log(process.env)` my url isn't doesn't show up.

[image: process.env printing]

My React app was created using the `create-react-app` cli a couple days of ago. My React App is deployed via github actions with the following startup command: (`pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/build --no-daemon --spa`)

From what I've read online it "should" just work, so I'm not sure what the breakdown is. My thought is something with pm2 might be blocking environmental variables, but not sure.

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52384934/azure-cant-access-env-variable-in-react-web-app) seems to be having a similar problem to me, but no answer is elaborated on that question. And I don't want to store config in package.json, since that's what Azure Config is suppose to help me do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A react single page app is, from an infrastructure perspective, just a bunch of static files - HTML,JS,CSS, whatever. It cannot reach into the server to read those variables because there is no server side code running.

You're going to have to bundle your environment variables, whether inside `.env` or `package.json` or wherever.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't considered that it wasn't feasible. Let me dig into those options.